# how to have vertical scroll in a separate column in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, scroll

I've got a grid in JQGrid
my list is long so there're a vertical scroll on the right

but this scroll bar is on the last column not on a separate on the right 
like this
[image]

how can i make it in a separate column ?

to see the bad result: [here](http://jsbin.com/ajugiz/1)

to see the code: [here](http://jsbin.com/ajugiz/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Add in a blank column at the end and then the scroll bar will go there.

To do so append a blank value to your data rows in your grid setup via:

```
        beforeProcessing: function (data, status, xhr) {
            //add the spaces to the returned data to allow for the blank vertical columns in the grid
            for (var x = 0, length = data.rows.length; x < length; x++) {
                data.rows[x].cell.splice(5,0, "");
            }//for
        }, //beforeProcessing
```

Add an extra value to your columns:

```
 'Fournisseur<br/>Commande',
              'Contenu', ''],
```

then add in the blank column definition:

```
 { name: "empty1", width: 10, sortable: false, hidedlg: true, search: false, resizable: false, fixed: true },
```

Comment: this solution work in Firefox but not in Chrome and i need it for Chrome in priority